# Is this the Drupal Forum module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Could somebody tell me which drupal module is this site using: http://gallery.menalto.com/forum

Also could somebody tell me how it'd be if I use it on my new site for forum discussion for 2000 people daily? I'm looking for simple discussion forum with following functionality:

- Easy maintenance
- I should be able to easily remove spammy user posts
- Some sort of spam prevention.

I'd be using Drupal-6 and not 7.

Comment: Folks I've started another related thread, your comments are welcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775634/which-one-will-be-better-phpbb-or-advanced-forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the link you provide is the Drupal forum.

Drupal isn't exactly famous for its forum - some sites even use third party forums which are bridged to Drupal.

Nonetheless, the most "direct" and easy-to-maintain forum for Drupal would probably be Drupal itself.

You can use Mollum for spam prevention.

The third-party forums primarily distinguish themselves in offering granular privileges to moderators of specific forums.  If you don't need this, I'd stick with the Drupal forum module.

Notice also **Erik Ahlswede**'s answer here - in addition to the standard Drupal Forum, it appears to be running the Advanced Forum module, which provides some of the extra functionalities - however, as **Michele** notes, it this isn't actually the Advanced Forum module, it's some hacks which provide similar functionalities.

Comment: That's nice and I'm not at all looking for granular privileges. Minimum needed is "disciplining the forum" in easy way. Long term easy maintainence. I hope this is what you say

Comment: Yes, user - that's what I say, so I think you will be happy with the standard Drupal forum.

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't using Advanced Forum. They are using Drupal's forum but *heavily* customized. They customized their forum before AF even existed, back in D5. If their changelog is accurate, they haven't upgraded.

That said, if you want a site that looks like that, AF will get you pretty close. With 2K people daily, do you mean visitors or active posters? One thing you need to watch out for is performance as Drupal's forum has a couple nasty queries and AF has them as well since it builds on top.

For a bit of trivia... I actually came to Drupal when looking for something to let me add text to my Gallery 2 site and their forum was an inspiration for AF in the early days. :)

Michelle

Comment: Michelle, thanks I think I should go for phpBB because if my site is  successful, I can migrate easily to vBulletin. But with Drupal forum/AF I think migration to vBulletin will be very difficult. What do you say?

Comment: I noticed Gallery's forum as well and it's inspired me as well.

Comment: I don't have any experience migrating from Drupal to any other forum software so I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That may be the [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module.  It extends Drupals core module and adds ways to create forum themes.

Comment: I prefer the Advanced Forum module with Drupal Forums, I actually think it(menalto) might be it or else it's a customised View, which is what the AF module does too, AF needs views to work

Comment: Advanced Forum also provides some execution optimization by axing features which involve resource-extensive queries.

Comment: Yes, it does look like Advanced Forum module ... though note, it's still the Drupal Forum - Advanced Forum runs "on top" of Drupal Forum and adds the author pane & some other features.  Thanks for adding that, I should have mentioned this in my own answer.

Comment: It isn't AF(pl. see answers below)